# Modifying the font head and size inside \section in emacs editor

Tags: emacs

I am running Emacs 23 with AUCTeX for editing LaTeX source files. I'd like to be able to customise the font head and size of the section name.

To make things absolutely clear, the font inside the `\section{}` command, becomes slightly bigger in size and into a font head different from the rest of the buffer. Is it possible to customize this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the cursor inside the curly brackets in `\section{}` (with some words inside the curly brackets), then type

> M-x customize-face RET RET

and you will see the set of customisations for that face. In my emacs they are

[image]

You need to change the scale in height to make it bigger/smaller, and you can change the colour in foreground. Don't forget to save for future sessions and to save your options so your customisations won't be lost.

Another two useful commands to customise faces in Emacs are

> M-x list-faces-display

which lists all faces in the display and

> M-x customize-group RET font-latex-highlighting-faces RET

to customise the latex-related faces.